# get_the_terms not working in custom plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have created custom plugin which stores the user data in db table. The form have dropdown which have taxonomy id as value.

The form is working and taxonomy id and other user data is inserting in the database.

In the wp admin panel i am showing the data that has been inserted in the database. All the data is coming with the taxonomy id. But when i use get_the_terms to get the name according to the taxonomy id it shows nothing.

### Here is the code:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name=$wpdb->prefix .'opu_userdata';
$data=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name order by id DESC");
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tow-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Sno</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Product Sub</th>
        <th>Annual Salary</th>
        <th>Employee Type</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php 
    $sn=1;
    foreach($data as $data):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $sn;?></td>
        <td><?php echo ucwords($data->name);?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->email;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->mobile;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->product;?></td>
        <td><?php
        if($data->product=="bank-account"){
            $id=$data->product_sub;
            $n=get_the_terms($id,'account_type');
            echo $id; /////if i echo id it prints the id perfectly but when i try $n[0]->name it shows nothing (var_dump($n) shows bool(false) )
        }?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->annual_salary;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->emp_type;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->age;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $sn++; endforeach;?>

</tbody>
```

Comment: You'll have to make sure that the `account_type` taxonomy is actually registered before the execution of the code above. This might not be contributing to a solution but also change the variable name after `as` in your loop to something else as the array you are iterating. For example `foreach ($data as $d)`

Comment: For getting name of taxonomy, have you use foreach or not?

Comment: @jrswgtr yes the taxonomy is registered and the id of the taxonomy is inserting in the database

Comment: @WPDeveloper this same line i am using in my front end for single post get_the_terms(get_the_id(),'account_type') and it is working perfectly. But in wp-admin it is not working

Comment: @denny I guess you need to write foreach loop to get name from `get_the_terms` like  ```foreach ( $n as $n_t ) {
        $name = $n_t->name;
        echo $name;
    }```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got the solution. I have to use get_term_by instead of get_the_terms to get the term name according to the taxonomy id

### Here is the solution:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tow-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Sno</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Product Sub</th>
        <th>Annual Salary</th>
        <th>Employee Type</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php 
    $sn=1;
    foreach($data as $d):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $sn;?></td>
        <td><?php echo ucwords($d->name);?></td>
        <td><?php echo $d->email;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $d->mobile;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $d->product;?></td>
        <td><?php
        if($d->product=="bank-account"){
            $id=$d->product_sub;
            $term=get_term_by('id',$id,'account_type');
            echo $term->name;
        }?></td>
        <td><?php echo $d->annual_salary;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $d->emp_type;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $d->age;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $sn++; endforeach;?>

</tbody>
```